# How do you enable auto-scrolling on GtkSourceView2?

Tags: python, gtk

I am having a problem with GtkSourceView used from Python.

Two major problems:
1) When a user types text into the GtkSourceView, and types past the bottom of the visible text, the GtkSourceView does not autoscroll to the users cursor.
This wouldnt be so bad, except:
2) The arrow keys, page up and page down keys, do not cause the GtkSourceView to scroll either.

The mouse scrollbar does work on the GtkSourceView.

Does anyone have knowledge/experience of this?

My code is here http://launchpad.net/kabikaboo

Comment: Ok, scratch that.  How do you hook into the keypress to enable scrolling?  Up, Down, PgUp, and PgDown keys need to work on this widget or it becomes frustrating.

Comment: I tried calling place_cursor_onscreen() from the keypress, but GtkSourceView2 does not honor it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just figured this out.

I was adding the GtkSourceView2 into a GtkScrolledWindow.
Only, it was adding a ViewPort first via ScrolledWindow.add_with_viewport().
This disables part of the scrolling behavior via keyboard.
Instead, use ScrolledWindow.add(), and the ViewPort is skipped and the GtkAdjustments take care of the scrolling!